# PHP set db value according to server datetime

Tags: php, datetime

Need to send notification to user by cron.
For that there is a datetime picker from which admin can select datetime.
IF datetime selected by datepicker is as below:

```
 $selecteddate = '26-9-2018 10:00';

 $defualttimzone = 'Asia/Kolkatta';

 $serverdate = date('d-m-Y H:i');
```

There is also a dropdown along with datetime picker with values:
       IND(GMT+3)
       USA(GMT-5)
       SAU(GMT+5)

Need to insert the date in database in reference to the current server's timezone and country selected along with datetime.
So that at exact time notification is sent to user.

```
       $milli = strtotime($selecteddate) * 1000;
```

Converted selected datetime to millseconds. Now i want to compare this milliseconds with server time and get difference and then get date from it to
insert in database.

Not getting how to move further. Any help would be appreciated.
Thankyou.